# provider hashicorp/google: no available releases match the given constraints. => Where do I specify which version I want?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-anthos

I'm trying to follow the [Upgrade Anthos Service Mesh on GKE with Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/terraform-asm-upgrade) guide.
But terraform init fails:

```
tf init
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/external...
- Finding hashicorp/google versions matching ">= 2.12.0, >= 3.53.0, < 4.0.0, >= 4.10.0, < 5.0.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/kubernetes versions matching "~> 2.0, ~> 2.10"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google-beta...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/null...
- Installing hashicorp/google-beta v4.21.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google-beta v4.21.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.2.0...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/null v3.1.1...
- Installed hashicorp/null v3.1.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/external v2.2.2...
- Installed hashicorp/external v2.2.2 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/kubernetes v2.11.0...
- Installed hashicorp/kubernetes v2.11.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/google: no available releases match the given constraints >= 2.12.0, >= 3.53.0, < 4.0.0, >= 4.10.0, < 5.0.0
```

The only version I can see being defined here is ASM 1.9.
There is no reference to `hashicorp/google` in the .tf files that were used to initialize the project.

How can I work around this?

I've tried with Terraform 1.1.9 and 1.2.0

Comment: This is an issue with conflicting provider versions specified in different declared modules. The `>= 4.10.0, < 5.0.0` originates from the GKE module. If you want to follow the article, then you will need to specify an old version of that module (and its associated ASM submodule) to be compatible with `~> 3.0.0` of the network module. Alternatively you can try it on your own with newer versions of the network module.

Comment: Matt's comment should be an answer! Thanks!